# Cannot open Parental Controls preference pane in Yosemite

Tags: macos, system-settings, parental-controls

I cannot open the Parental Controls preference pane in OS X Yosemite. It just gives me: "Preferences Error. Could not load preference pane."

Here are the console logs I got:

```
System Preferences[609]: an error occurred while attempting to connect to listener 'com.apple.view-bridge': Connection invalid
System Preferences[609]: *** Assertion failure in +[NSXPCSharedListener connectionForListenerNamed:fromServiceNamed:], /SourceCache/ViewBridge/ViewBridge-99/NSXPCSharedListener.m:394
System Preferences[609]: ### com.apple.preferences.parentalcontrols instantiatePrefPaneObject exception:NSXPCSharedListener unable to create endpoint for listener named com.apple.view-bridge
```

Comment: I'd run Disk Utility, repair perms, check disk, then if no joy, run the latest combo updater from https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1820

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Tetsujin](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/85275/tetsujin) said:

> I'd run Disk Utility, repair perms, check disk, then if no joy, run the latest combo updater from support.apple.com/kb/DL1820